# How to capture elements that display after button click - Python and Selenium used

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On my local email-provider, i wanted to check if my desired email-name is free for registration or not with using a easy python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions  # as EC
import time


def checkmymail():
    s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
    driver.get('https://meinkonto.telekom-dienste.de/telekom/email/registration/registration.xhtml')
    alias1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'j_idt58:j_idt98:j_idt100:j_idt101:j_idt108:emailAlias')
    alias1.send_keys("mywishmail25")
    sendb = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'j_idt58:j_idt98:j_idt100:j_idt148:checkEmailAlias')
    sendb.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    availability1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'form-input-plates')
    print(availability1)

checkmymail()
```

On this emailprovider a message box with text displays after clicking the confirmation-button which either says (in german) "this email is free for registration" (green text) or "this email isnt free" (in red text)

i try to capture and print the text box that opens up after clicking the button, but neither with using the ID or the Class name i have success in getting the element output.

How to achieve to capture this special type of element?

Comment: You can capture almost any elements in the page using XPath. 
As I see you want to get `availability1`. 
Before this line put this:
`print(driver.page_source)`
and save what is printed in the console in a .html file and share here with me.

Answer (score 0):

First
To manage to capture that message XPath , from your browser there is execution window next to network
Try to add stop point and take the full XPath

Second , try to find that element in the XPath helper
If you find it than you should be able to get element

If not and that is probably the case than you should check if there is any table or iframe  before the element than you should change your drive to the new frame

What you get ?